# Как при помощи move_uploaded_file загрузить один и тот же файл, полученный из formData в несколько разных папок?

Tags: php

Как при помощи move_uploaded_file загрузить один и тот же файл, полученный из formData в несколько разных папок?

Comment: Никак. Надо использовать копирование.

Comment: а точно несколько копий надо? может символической ссылки достаточно будет?

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $file);
copy($file, $file2);
copy($file, $file3);
copy($file, $file4);
```